# How high will the resolution be for OpenMapTiles Aerial/Satellite Imagery?

Tags: resolution, satellite, openmaptiles

So this is more of an inquiry,

I visited https://openmaptiles.com/satellite/ and it is my understanding that "Highres aerial imagery" is still to be added. So, my first question will this imagery comparable to the imagery we see in Google Maps and Bing Maps? I attached some of OpenMapTiles lower resolution imagery for comparison. Also, is there a scheduled release date for coverage of the US? Maybe I'm getting ahead of things here but will the imagery be available for download at a one time fee and will it be as affordable as the OpenStreetMap tiles?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is related to the cost to acquire high resolution data. At the moment, free data sources such as Sentinel-2, Landsat-8, and CBERS4 are 5m to 30m resolution. Higher resolution data like what one would see in Google Maps and Bing Map are very expensive as they require commercial satellite images or aereal photographs. The gov't and local municipalities often provide high-res geospatial data for free on their websites (like open data), if you need data for only a few urban area.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data isn't always free.  At least in my county the high resolution imagery is proprietary and reserved for use by municipalities as part of some kind of contract. You can view it all you want but can't download it for use in your own projects. Of course there are plenty of aerial photography vendors out there but like you said the imagery is expensive.